# GatsbyJS display directory of images with attributes for each image

Tags: gatsby

I want to display headshots of 50 employees along with their names and medical schools.

Right now I do this by making a named graphql query for each person in the directory. So there are 50 named queries. Here's a sample:

```
query = graphql`
  query {
    joeBond:file(relativePath:{ regex: "/joebond/"}) {
      ...headshotImage
    }
    janeReed:file(relativePath:{ regex: "/janereed/"}) {
      ...headshotImage
    }
```

Next I retrieve the graphql response and hardcode the name and medical school of the person in the photograph like so:

```
<HeadshotImage 
   imgSrc={data.joeBond} 
   fullName="Joe Bond" 
   medicalSchool="University of South Alabama" 
/>

<HeadshotImage 
   imgSrc={data.janeReed} 
   fullName="Jane Reed" 
   medicalSchool="University of Kentucky" 
 />
```

It would be more ideal if all items where in one coherent list such as:

```
const faceshots = [
  { 
    name: "Joe Bond", 
    medicalSchool: "U Kentucky", 
    image: "joebond.png" 
  },
  ....
]
```

But, I cannot figure out how to make a graphql query that could "link" up with such a list.

Does anyone have a recommended way to accomplish this problem?

Comment: are you pulling the info for the headshots from a doc ? Also [https://codebushi.com/using-gatsby-image/] docs for gatsby-image Using The Gatsby Image Component is the track you want.

Comment: I am not pulling the info from a doc, but I would like to. That would be an improvement over what I’ve coded. The code uses Gatsby Image Component to render the image.